# Filepath with a string Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, filepath

I am trying to get random text files from Resources folder to be shown in Textview. I could not do this because i could not get that **1** in pathForResource:@"**1**" increment. How can I increment that **1** after **@**. Thanks.

Note: I am trying to use stringb there but it does not work.

```
int b=(arc4random()%9)+1;

NSString *stringb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", b];


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"txt"];  
if (filePath) {  
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (myText) {  
        textView1.text= myText;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment an integer variable and create a string using it:

```
static int number = 1;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number++] ofType:@"txt"];
...
```

I assumed that this method is the only one which will access the variable. If not you will either need to make `number` an instance variable or a global variable.